# Change the space between UICollecionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a CollectionView. Here is the implementation for my CollectionView.

```
- (void)setupCollectionView{
    self.flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [self.flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)];
    self.flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(150, 35);
    self.flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20;
    [self.flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    self.vwCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.vwQuickReplyContainer.frame.size.width, self.vwQuickReplyContainer.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout];
    self.vwCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.vwCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"QuickrepliesCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"QuickrepliesCell"];
    [self.vwQuickReplyContainer addSubview:self.vwCollectionView];
    self.vwQuickReplyContainer.hidden = YES;
    [self.vwCollectionView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

    [self.vwCollectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.vwCollectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.vwCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Here I set the minimumLineSpacing to set the minimum spacing between successive columns. According to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617705-collectionview?language=objc), I understand that value represents the minimum spacing between successive columns for a horizontally scrolling grid. I was also set the space between my cells. Here is the outcomes of doing that [image].

But to get more looking good. I want to change my cell's width according to its content's size. So I've updated my cell's frame like this.

```
- (QuickrepliesCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"QuickrepliesCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    QuickReply *model = [[QuickReply alloc]initWithDictionary:self.quickRepliesArr[indexPath.row] error:nil];
    self.cell.lblOpion.text = model.title;
    CGFloat width =  [self.cell.lblOpion.text sizeWithFont:WWLATOREGULAR(15)].width;
    self.cell.frame = CGRectMake(self.cell.frame.origin.x, self.cell.frame.origin.y, width + 24, self.cell.frame.size.height);
    return self.cell;
}
```

Here is the outcomes after updating the cell's width.[image].

I don't know the reason why the space between my cells was changed after changing the cell's size. Can anyone advice on this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve it, you need to calculate and change item size in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
- (QuickrepliesCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  self.cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"QuickrepliesCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  QuickReply *model = [[QuickReply alloc]initWithDictionary:self.quickRepliesArr[indexPath.row] error:nil];
  self.cell.lblOpion.text = model.title;
  return self.cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  QuickReply *model = [[QuickReply alloc]initWithDictionary:self.quickRepliesArr[indexPath.row] error:nil];
  CGFloat width =  [model.title sizeWithFont:WWLATOREGULAR(15)].width;
  return CGSizeMake(width + 24, 35);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the `itemSize` property of the layout to fixed size, implement the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` layout delegate method.

Then you can set the proper size of each item.